# Which passage from the Scripture and the holy texts forbids human sacrifice?

Tags: scripture, vedas, rituals, sacrifice

I have been searching for the passage from the Vedas that puts an eternal ban on the practice of human sacrifice.

If there isn't a passage from the Vedas forbidding human sacrifice, than find the next highest authority that forbids human sacrifice.

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purushamedha) is a fair representation on the take of scriptures with regards to Human sacrifice.

Comment: You have the question reversed. Scripture says what is allowed. We are enjoined to follow what scripture says to do. Anything beyond what scripture allows is forbidden, outside of dharma. Your question should be - Does scripture call for human sacrifice?